# Hide activity comments form when changing tab

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

By default Buddypress opens the comments form when clicking a new tab (All members, My friends, My favorites, ...).

Is it someone could tell me how not to display this form please ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires editing a core Buddypress file.
If anyone know how to do this via theme files, please post.

In `wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc/global.js`, you'll find a function called `bp_activity_request` around line 1143.

Modify the `jq('div.activity').fadeOut()` callback thusly:

Before:

```
jq('div.activity').fadeOut( 100, function() {
    jq(this).html(response.contents);
    jq(this).fadeIn(100);

    /* Selectively hide comments */
    bp_dtheme_hide_comments();
});
```

After:

```
jq('div.activity').fadeOut( 100, function() {
    jq(this).html(response.contents);
    jq('form.ac-form').hide(); // added line to hide forms
    jq(this).fadeIn(100);

    /* Selectively hide comments */
    bp_dtheme_hide_comments();
});
```